# Keras model.fit() - which training algorithm is used?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, theano

I am using Keras on top of Theano to create a MLP which I train and use to predict time series. Independently of the structure and depth of my network I cannot figure out (Keras documentation, StackOverflow, searching the net...) which training algorithm (Backpropagation,...) Keras' `model.fit()` function is using.
Within Theano (used without Keras before) I could define the way the parameters are adjusted myself with

```python
self.train_step = theano.function(inputs=[u_in, t_in, lrate], outputs=[cost, y],
                                      on_unused_input='warn',
                                      updates=[(p, p - lrate * g) for p, g in zip(self.parameters, self.gradients)],
                                      allow_input_downcast=True)
```

Not finding any information causes a certain fear that I am missing something essential and that this may be a totally stupid question.
Can anybody help me out here? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It depends on the optimizer. Maybe take a look at [optimizers.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py)? Your provided Theano update rule should be equivalent to `SGD(momentum=0., nesterov=False)`.

Comment: In keras, training algorithm and loss function are adjusted in "model.compile" method.

Comment: Thanks guys. There is an article I have found and can recommend regarding this topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py):

```
...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
...
```

model.fit does **not** use an algorithm to predict the outcome, rather it uses the model you describe.  The optimiser algorithm is then specified in model.compile

e.g.

```
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=**keras.optimizers.Adadelta()**,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You can find out more about the available optimisers here : https://keras.io/optimizers/